# How to obtain a slope by moving a line?

Tags: python, excel, vba, plot

I am wondering if there is any possible way how to obtain the slope of a line that I move manually on a graph. All is need is the slope (m) and I do not care about the R square, etc. The image below is just for illustration.

NOTE: The line should be moved manually using the cursor.

It might be not possible in excel, but if you have any idea where I should start looking, it will be useful! Thanks.

[image]

Comment: As far as moving points with a mouse, possible but not easy. See [this article](https://peltiertech.com/chart-events-microsoft-excel/) about how to enable events for embedded charts. Once you enable them, the trickiest part is relating mouse coordinates and axes coordinates. It can be a headache to get right. It might be easiest to have a 1-point data series and figure out how to detect when it is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obtaining the actual (literal) slope of the line is fairly straightforward, even though the line doesn't expose it's endpoints, we can use its `.Top`, `.Left`, `.Height` and `.Width` properties to derive those, and then apply the standard slope formula:

```vb
Function GetSlope(thisLine As Shape)
Dim ret
If Not IsLine(thisLine) Then
    ret = CVErr(13)
    GoTo EarlyExit
End If

Dim x1 As Single, x2 As Single, y1 As Single, y2 As Single

With thisLine
    x1 = .Left
    x2 = .Left + .Width
    y1 = .Top
    y2 = .Top + .Height
End With

ret = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
EarlyExit:
    GetSlope = ret
End Function

Private Function IsLine(shp As Shape) As Boolean
IsLine = shp.Type = msoLine
End Function
```

**HOWEVER** (and this may be a deal-breaker depending on what you actually hope to obtain here), this is **NOT LIKELY** the slope relative to the plot area, which depends on the size and scale of the axes. For example, the following chart plots a series of x/y coordinates and the slope given as `y = 2x`, yet the slope given by the `GetSlope` function (for a Line shape with an approximately same slope) returns `0.9166661` which is the literal slope of this line from its positional coordinates.

[image]

It seems you may need a further hack to approximate (I'm not sure how precisely you can implement this) the X/Y coordinates of the line's endpoints within the plot/scale. I think this will get you there, or mostly there, within some reasonable precision:

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub foo()
Dim cObj As ChartObject
Dim cht As Chart
Dim shpLine As Shape
Dim shp As Shape

Set cObj = Sheet1.ChartObjects(1)
Set cht = cObj.Chart
Set shpLine = cht.Shapes(1)

MsgBox GetSlopeWithinChart(shpLine, cht)

End Sub
Function GetSlopeWithinChart(thisLine As Shape, cht As Chart)
Dim ret
If Not IsLine(thisLine) Then
    ret = CVErr(13)
    GoTo EarlyExit
End If

Dim x1 As Single, x2 As Single, y1 As Single, y2 As Single
Dim plot As PlotArea
Dim xFactor As Double
Dim yFactor As Double

Set plot = cht.PlotArea

xFactor = getScaleFactor(plot.Width, cht.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary))
yFactor = getScaleFactor(plot.Height, cht.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary))

With thisLine
    x1 = .Left
    x2 = .Left + .Width
    y1 = .Top
    y2 = .Top + .Height
End With

ret = ((y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)) / (yFactor / xFactor)

EarlyExit:
    GetSlopeWithinChart = ret

End Function
Private Function getScaleFactor(size As Single, ax As Axis)
    getScaleFactor = size / (ax.MaximumScale - ax.MinimumScale)
End Function
Private Function IsLine(shp As Shape) As Boolean
IsLine = shp.Type = msoLine
End Function
```

[image]

Another test with a slope which we expect to be ~10:

[image]

**NOTE:** This does not seem to account for the "orientation" of the line, so it won't properly give you a negative slope value for a line that's oriented with a downward slope. I'm not sure there's an easy way to derive the line's orientation, so I'll leave that up to you :) Here we see this, a positive slope value even though the line appears oriented downwards:

[image]

Comment: While using the function in a macro, I am calling "thisLine" as "Straight Connector 2" and "Chart" as "Chart 1". However, I am getting an error: Type mismatch for thisLine. Can you show me how you're referring to thisLine?

Comment: `thisLine As Shape, cht As Chart`. These are the *objects*, not their names or strings. So, e.g., `GetSlopeWithinChart(ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.Shapes(1), ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart)`. Pass the actual objects to the function. NB this was tested using a line that *belongs to the Chart* rather than the sheet.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the test procedure `foo` that I used.

Comment: Thanks David, it is working properly. I will be trying to improve the accuracy as it is off around 4% in my computer. I really like your approach!

Comment: Cheers. This was an interesting problem to solve :)  Some other thing you *might* need to consider is the thickness of the axes which may slightly affect the size of the plot area -- there's a few little things like that which might get in the way. But ultimately, if you do this to 1 or maybe 2 decimals you should be pretty accurate in most cases.